# How to destroy Android Room Database instance?

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

I am creating a database as shown in the below code.

```
Room.databaseBuilder(MyApp.getInstance().getApplicationContext(), MyDatabase.class, "my-room-database").build();
```

I want to delete all the data, table and if possible the database itself when user logged out of the app since the data being stored is that user's personal data.

On user logout I tried doing the below but it doesn't work.

```
public static void destroyInstance() {
    if(petCareDatabase != null) {
        petCareDatabase.clearAllTables();
    }
    petCareDatabase = null;
}
```

Can someone help me find the right way to clean up the database when needed.

Comment: check this https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#15

Comment: @NileshRathod Couldn't find anything to delete/destroy the data. I don't want to go and delete the data from each and every table because in future the number of table will be large.

Answer (score 1):

Create a public static instance method to make the db instance null

```
 

            public abstract class DepotDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

               private static AppDatabase INSTANCE;

               public abstract UserDao userDao();

               public static AppDatabase getAppDatabase(Context context) {
               if (INSTANCE == null) {
                   INSTANCE = 
                         Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), 
                         AppDatabase.class, "user-database")
                            .allowMainThreadQueries()//Use Caution here
                            .build();
               }
               return INSTANCE;
              }
              public static void destroyInstance() {
                INSTANCE = null;
                 }
               }
```

Then in the main activity or the activity using it

```
 

        @Override
             protected void onDestroy() {
             AppDatabase.destroyInstance();
             super.onDestroy();
        }
```

Comment: What if I am using it in a `MVVM` structure? The only reference to it is done in `AndroidViewModel` extended class.